# SwiftUI View not displaying data properly

Tags: arrays, swift, database, sqlite, swiftui

I have one View that allows the user to select exercises from a list (NewRoutine), assign them to a day of the week, and then save them. Then I have another view that displays the exercises that the user selected, organized by day of the week (YourRoutines). However, in testing when I select multiple exercises and assign them to one day, they're not displayed properly in the other view. Only the first exercise that I selected is displayed. This the code for the view that should display the exercises selected:

```
import SwiftUI
import SQLite3

struct YourRoutines: View
{
    @State private var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    
    @ObservedObject var routinedatabase: RoutineDatabase

    var body: some View
    {
        ZStack
        {
            ScrollView
            {
                ForEach($days, id: \.self)
                { day in
                    
                    VStack
                    {
                        Text(day.wrappedValue)
                            .font(.title.bold())
                            .padding(.bottom, 5)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        
                        ForEach(routinedatabase.routineList)
                        { routine in
                            if day.wrappedValue == routine.Day
                            {
                                Text(routine.Exercise)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for my database:

```
import SQLite3

struct Routines : Identifiable
{
    var id = UUID()
    var dbID : Int
    var routineID : Int
    var Exercise: String
    var Day: String
}

class RoutineDatabase : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var routineList = [Routines]()
    @Published var routineIDMax = 0
    @Published var dbIDMax = 0
    
    init()
    {
        var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            return formatter
        }
        var stmt : OpaquePointer?
        
        let dbURL: URL = {
            let fileName: String = "ShapeShiftDB.db"
            
            let fileManager:FileManager = FileManager.default
            let directory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            
            let documentUrl = directory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            let bundleUrl = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            
            // here check if file already exists on simulator
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (documentUrl.path)) {
                print("document file exists!")
                return documentUrl
            }
            else if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (bundleUrl?.path)!) {
                print("document file does not exist, copy from bundle!")
                do
                {
                    print(bundleUrl!.path)
                    try fileManager.copyItem(at:bundleUrl!, to:documentUrl)
                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Unable to copy item: \(error)")
                }
            }
            return documentUrl
        }()
        
        if sqlite3_open_v2(String(dbURL.path), &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            print(dbURL.path)
            print("Error66:" + String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))
            sqlite3_close(db)
            
            //Else if database opens successfully...
        }
        else {
            
            let routineTable = "SELECT * FROM Routines;"
            
            if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, routineTable, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK
            {
                while sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW
                {
                    let dbID = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0))
                    let routineID = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1))
                    let name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))
                    let day = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))
                    if routineID > routineIDMax {routineIDMax = routineID}
                    if dbID > dbIDMax {dbIDMax = dbID}
                    
                    routineList.append(Routines(dbID: dbID, routineID: routineID, Exercise: name, Day: day))
                }
            }
            else {
                print(dbURL.path)
                print("Error92:" + String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))
                sqlite3_close(db)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had this problem before and I fixed it because I'd forgotten to keep incrementing dbIDMax in one of the loops. That fixed it and it worked fine, but after checking back on it after a while it stopped working. I don't get any errors so I don't know what's wrong.